# How to convert variables from MYSQL result into PHP variables with same name?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this mysql query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  userdetails WHERE  userid= '$userid'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The result is a row of 100 variables with different names such as $row['name'], and $row['email'], etc...

How can I convert all of these to just $name and $email, etc... in php?

It would save so much time to write this program....

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to pass around 100 variables instead of one array.

Comment: because the rest of my code is written in those variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short anwser: extract

long anwser : don't. It may seem like a good anwser now but if you use it much it will become a problem keeping track of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/extract

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't ultimately want to do that, but the extract() function does this.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php